# How do I get rid of white dots appearing next to my Navbar links in a bootstrap template?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am currently using [this template](https://sharebootstrap.com/art-studio-minimal-studio-template/) from ShareBootstrap. So far it is working perfectly fine, except for this one bug: White dots labeled as `li.nav-tem::marker` are appearing about an inch to the left of each Navbar link.

Information about my issue:

- I have checked the code for anything mentioning nav-item, marker, or any other combination of the terms.
- There is no mention of a marker in the HTML.
- It appears in every HTML page containing the navbar.
  I have not edited the CSS.
- This appeared after adding a new navbar link, but I changed no other related code when I made the change.
- Other than the added link, the HTML navbar code looks identical.
- When I remove the new link I added, the problem persists.

Here is a github repository with my current code in it.
https://github.com/dritchkid/portfolio

Note: I am aware that I don't have the repository set up with pages. I'm currently just testing on my computer for now.

[Image of the white dots in question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYyia.png)

Where are these dots coming from? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the dots by setting the list style on the `navbar-nav` class, which is on the `ul`.

```css
.navbar-nav {
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Dumb question: Which file would I put that code in? It doesn't work in assets/css/main.css

I don't know what other files it could go in.